# How to reverse ES6 API Intl.DisplayNames() region value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-intl

I need to **reverse** this condtion, That means `United States` to `US`. I try to find out on **Google** but can't. How can I do it?

```js
let regionNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], {type: 'region'});
console.log(regionNames.of('US'));  // "United States"
```

Comment: One problem here is that the _code_ can be either an [ISO-3166 two letters region code](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html), or a [three digits UN M49 Geographic Regions](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/) so it's unclear what result you actually want. AFAIK, there is no reverse lookup other than creating your own inverse map

Answer (score 0):

This library should help

https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-code-lookup

```
// search by country name
lookup.byCountry('United Kingdom')
```